# Background image not found

Tags: css, symfony, twig

In a symfony application I render a twig template containing some internal css.
For the main element I want to insert a background image:

```
main {
  height: 85%;
  background: url('intro-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Both the image 'intro-bg.jpg' as well as the twig template lie in the same folder templates/students/public.
I read that the path given to the url has to be relative to the template, and thus it should fit, still the .jpg doesn't get found.
Can anybody tell me, what would be the correct path?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: It should be a relative path to the CSS file, not the twig template.

Comment: Where is located the file in your directory?

Comment: the twig template of which I gave the excerpt and the file 'intro-bg.jpg' both lie in the same directory: templates/students/public

Comment: @Toby thanks, but the CSS is included in the head of the twig template

Comment: Symfony 3 or 4? It's important to give such details...

Comment: @Kevin it does not matter where it is included, you should provide path relative to css file

Comment: @Kevin and before replying to someone who is giving you a hint, give it a try then give your opinion

Comment: @Preciel Symfony 4

Comment: @Antihype No, it was not supposed to sound disrespectful, i'm glad for the hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn`t matter where located your twig template. url() is relative to the folder structure of your website (not your project). According to your example your file must be in same public folder as css file or in case of internal css in same folder as the requested page.

Better to use url with leading slash. In this case you can put an url relative to your root folder of website. For example, your image located in /public/students/intro-bg.jpg, so you can get it by url *http://your_site/students/intro-bg.jpg* or in css *url('/students/intro-bg.jpg')*

Comment: okay, thank you @Roman! then I was thinking in the wrong direction. but where can i create this folder /public/student/ you mentioned, so that the image is accessible via http://your_site/students/intro-bg.jpg? not in the project? i am using the server that is contained in symfony.

Comment: Symfony has a folder /public in the root of project. This folder by default is the root of your website. So you can create there some img folder, where you can manage storage of all public available images. You can get access this folder by http://your_site/img/